# Using SqlBulkCopy, how do I insert data into a table in a non-default database schema?

Tags: .net, schema, sqlbulkcopy, database-schema

I need to insert data into a table in a schema named `Staging` using `SqlBulkCopy`.

It appears the API only allows you to set the target table name by using the `DestinationTableName` property.

How do I accomplish this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While the API does not provide an explicit interface to set the destination schema, you can actually stuff a 2- or 3-part qualified table name into the [DestinationTableName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.destinationtablename(v=VS.90).aspx) property like so:

```
b.DestinationTableName = string.Format("[{0}].[{1}]", schemaName, tableName);
```

or

```
b.DestinationTableName =
    string.Format("[{0}].[{1}].[{2}]", databaseName, schemaName, tableName);
```

Given that [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) has always supported a fully-qualified table name, it seems like a big oversight that those separate components never made it into the API.

Moreover, as it appears that `DestinationTableName` is simply output into a `BULK INSERT` statement, this property may be vulnerable to SQL injection. So if you're getting this information from a user at some point, make sure to sanitize the input before running this operation.